# Finding a basis for a subspace. Do i always need to test linearly independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Where the subspace is contained in {[5r-3s;2r;0;-4s] is an element of R^4: r and s are scalars}

The generating set that can make up all of the input is {[5;2;0;0], [-3;0;0;-4]}

This is only a generating set however, do we have to see if it is also linearly independent in this specific case.  I know that a basis is a linearly independent generating set that spans the subspace.

Comment: Yes, you have to test for linear independence of the set, otherwise it would only be a spanning set, and not a basis. You can easily have spanning sets that are not bases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at the definition of a basis:

A set of vectors in a vector space V is called a basis, or a set of basis vectors, if the vectors are linearly independent and every other vector in the vector space is linearly dependent on these vectors. In more general terms, a basis is a linearly independent spanning set.

Comment: So Yes, not no.

Comment: @Bubbletea yes, you do. that was a typo. sorry